# Layer iteration in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis, iteration

I have been reviewing all the questions on the site that are similar to mine. I have code that was sourced from Graphical Modeler. Now I need to iterate the dots2 layer using Python. I understand that it is necessary to use 'for i in range', but I did not succeed in implementing this. This "miracle" button [image] is not suitable for me this time.

```
class Test(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('dots2', 'dots2', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('trees2', 'trees2', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Result', 'Result', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(13, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'FIELD': 'id',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': ['N1','L1'],
            'FIELD_2': 'N1',
            'INPUT': parameters['trees2'],
            'INPUT_2': parameters['dots2'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'FIELD': 'id',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': ['L2'],
            'FIELD_2': 'N2',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_2': parameters['dots2'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'FIELD': 'id',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': ['L3'],
            'FIELD_2': 'N3',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_2': parameters['dots2'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 5,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'L',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 10,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'concat(L1,L2,L3)',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'L',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'D + L',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'L',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'coalesce(\"l\", 0)',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'FIELD': 'l',
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 15,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('qgis:variabledistancebuffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:polygonstolines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
            'INTERSECT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INTERSECT_FIELDS': [''],
            'INTERSECT_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:lineintersections', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': 0.25,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 10,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:polygonstolines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
            'INTERSECT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'INTERSECT_FIELDS': [''],
            'INTERSECT_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:lineintersections', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(12)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['']['OUTPUT'],
            'UID': '',
            'WEIGHT': '',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Result']
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:meancoordinates', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Result'] = outputs['']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'test'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'test'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Test()
```

***UPDATE.***

Let me briefly get to the heart of the matter. The Trees layer has data about points with known coordinates. The dots2 layer is feature data, with unknown coordinates but calculated distances from three points in the Trees layer to each dots2 feature. Thus, for each dots2 object, there are 3 columns with the corresponding point number of the trees layer (N1, N2, N3) and 3 columns with the distance to this point (L1, L2, L3). Thus, as a result of the entire algorithm, we will obtain the coordinates of unknown points by distances up to three known ones. The algorithm will only work if you run it in iteration mode to the dots2 layer (I hope I put it clearly). The iteration button helped me, but now I need to do it through Python for further work

Comment: A basic example would be something like: `dots2_src = self.parameterAsSource(parameters,  'dots2', context)` `for f in dots2_src.getFeatures():` `#do something with f...` Hard to answer because you haven't really said what you want to do and how it relates to the existing steps in the  exported model code.

Comment: @BenW I've updated my text, check it out first. Your code starts iteration, but not in the desired mode. For simplicity, I would reduce the code to the first three algorithms, in which columns L1, L2, L3 from the dots2 layer are attached to the trees layer in turn. They are joined by columns N1, N2, N3, where, as you know, data on the points of trees are given. Thus, having, for example, 12 objects in the dots2 layer, we get 12 layers of trees at the output, each of which has one row attached from each column L1, L2, L3. This is how it works when the "Iteration" button is pressed.

Comment: @BenW But in the case of the code you sent me, the algorithm appends all the data from the dots2 layer to the trees layer 12 times. That is, the algorithm repeats not the same action for each individual object of the dots2 layer, but for the entire dots2 layer.